# Fire an event in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mule

Currently I am working on a project where we have to send an SMS to all the users who are enrolled for auto-renewal, before 24 hours of their current expiration date that their subscription will be renewed.

Right after the moment the subscription expires and the auto-renewal is set on the account, we deduct certain amount from the customer's balance. Since the balance on the customer's account changes very quickly, we have to fire an event as soon as the subscription expires. We use an external service to check if the customer has enough balance to renew. So this check has to be asynchronous.

How can I run a job that runs continuously to loop through all the records in the table and fire an event that fetches the balance asynchronously?

We are using Mule, Spring and Hibernate and application runs on Tomcat.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Instead of the renewal system triggering the auto renewal process, wouldn't it be a better idea if the customer himself triggers it? What I mean by this is, if you can find a way such that every time the customer finishes using some service for which he is charged, your system should be notified of the change in the account balance along with the customer id. You can monitor these notifications instead of waiting for the data to be inserted in the db and then iterating over each row in the tables.

Comment: @bot actually the subscription cost is fixed and its monthly. Its the customer's prepaid mobile balance. So we charge the customer for the renewal from the mobile balance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you schedule the job rather than continuously looping to find jobs?

If so, using a scheduler such as [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) may be the best solution. It integrates well with Spring and can be persisted in whatever database that you already have configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually using Mule ESB, please take a look at following components:

- [Pool](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Poll+Reference)
- [Asynchronous](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Async+Scope+Reference)
- [DB connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector)

From the top of my head that's enough components to build the use case you've just described.

Additionally you may want to take a look to:

- [Batch module](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing)

Which is designed to handle use cases similar to what you have just described.

Depending on how you plan to implement this you may wish to use the:

- [scatter-gather](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather) component too.

Finally, please take a look to the [Anypoint Exchange](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange) to see example of all the components listed above together.

HTH

Comment: unfortunately the version of mule(3.4)  that we are on doesnt have all the features that you mentioned above

Comment: That's correct and FYI batch is EE  only :( I didn't mention it. 
Can't you upgrade to a new version ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use db connector inside polling scope and get the matched records then use the for-each scope and use the SMTP connector to send the message to each user user.